# Populate database with values from hash

Tags: ruby, database, activerecord, serialization

I'm still pretty new to Ruby, and having a tough time with easily pushing data into my db..I have this array of hashes

```
mine = [{:sellersku=>"2273500028", :asin=>"B0076E32F8", :price=>"15.49"}, 
{:sellersku=>"5154464774", :asin=>"B00013J6HY", :price=>"445.94"}, 
{:sellersku=>"5164589013", :asin=>"B007CB4OFM", :price=>"51.62"}]
```

and I want to put it into this table

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "sellersku"
t.string   "asin"
t.string   "price"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

What's the best way to do this? I don't want to save the entire hash in one column, the hash keys correspond to db column names.. The following gives me an error

```
first = Product.new
first.sellersku = "2273500028"
first.save
```

Same with Product.create

Error is

```
uninitialized constant Product (NameError)
```

I want to do this in the most efficient manner, my array will reach 5 to 6,000 hashes and I need to be able to quickly access the data..

Comment: I may be missing something, are you wanting to save the entire hash as one entry in the database or are you wanting to parse the array and save each entry as a product in the database?  At a minimum you don't have the constant Product defined in your app.

Comment: It seems you have not required your AR model. If you are in Rails, do `rails console`, or write a migration to import it for you - both of those will automatically require your models for you. Otherwise, you might need to `require_relative "models/product.rb"` or something similar before you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a rails app, do you have a product.rb file in your models folder?

It would contain at a minimum the class definition:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  #add whatever else you need in here
end
```

You'll have to decide how you want to allow your Products to be initialized. You can let them be initialized with all the params you already have, or you can do it line by line after creating the object.

Using the `mine` variable from your example, a simple way to save each hash as a new row would be to loop over it and create each row as you go.

```
mine.each do |product_to_save|
  product = Product.new
  product.sellersku = product_to_save[:sellersku]
  product.asin = product_to_save[:asin]
  product.price = product_to_save[:price]
  product.save
end
```

That's a simplified way of doing it. You may want to use the hash when initializing the new record if your model allows it:

```
mine.each do |product_to_save|
  product = Product.new(product_to_save)
  product.save
end
```

You could use map and shorthand the entire process like this:

```
mine.map{|product_to_save| Product.new(product_to_save).save}
```

or

```
mine.map{|product_to_save| Product.create(product_to_save)}
```